variable counter in table template with fitnesse automation
is it possible to create variables with a counter in fitnesse with table template, like a data dictionary or an array
for example:
|table template|customers|
|customers|
|name|surname|birthdate|
|john|black|04/02/1990|
|peter|white|04/02/1975|
|michael|grey|04/02/1960|

i want to create an output something like
|$customername1= |echo|john| OR (to give the idea like in json) $customername1: john
|$customersurname1= |echo|black|
|$customerbirthdate1= |echo|04/02/1990|
|$customername2= |echo|peter|
|$customersurname2= |echo|white|

so basically with every row i want to create a variable with a counter.
can anybody help me out, thanks
havent been able to think of anything, some fixture what can do this?

In the 2nd table in your question you are creating a set of Slim variables, with a counter embedded in their name. Is that what you want or do you really want a 'dictionary' or 'hash' that your fixtures can then access?

In my project hsac-fitnesse-fixtures I have a couple of fixtures that might help if you are looking to create lists, or maps/dictionaries to be stored in slim variables that you can then pass to fixtures.

ListFixture
MapFixture
MapOfMapsFixture

The latter for instance allows you to do
|table:map of maps fixture|
|     |NL  |EN            |
|dog  |Hond|Dog           |
|cat  |Kat |Cat           |
|$all=|$nl=|$en=          |

We can check the top level map.
|script|map fixture|$all      |
|check |size of    |NL    |2  |
|check |size of    |EN    |2  |
|check |value      |EN.dog|Dog|

We can check each column's variable.
|script|map fixture|$nl     |
|check |value      |dog|Hond|
|check |value      |cat|Kat |

|script|map fixture|$en    |
|check |value      |dog|Dog|
|check |value      |cat|Cat|

